# Check if a Date field is greater than another Date field

Tags: list, development, column, validation

I am working on an issue tracking list and I added two custom fields of type `Date/Time` which allows date only, as follow:

- Plan start date.
- Plan end date.

How can I check that the `start date` is always less than or equal to `end date`?

I am seeking a way that will work inside the quick edit grid & inside the built-in create/edit forms ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How you can do this:**

1. Open your list and open the list settings
2. Select the column "Plan start date"
3. Under Validation setting type in the below formula :

> `[Plan start date]<=[Plan end date]`

[image]

This help you to validate your dates before saving them.

Hope this helps !

Comment: worked perfectly